# Change Text in Button As Program Runs using value changing as timer runs

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, toolbox

I am trying to create a timer system, that shows the time taken by the player as they spend time on a level, that updates in real time (using the form timer). I have used a timer (mnTimer) in the form to account for movement etc.
I created a private float value at the top of the program, called game_Ticks:

```
public partial class Tutorial : Form
{
    private float game_Ticks;
    public Tutorial()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

I then set this value to increement as the form timer ticks;

```
private void mnTimer(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        game_Ticks++;
```

I am trying to make the text shown on a button (called time_Display) change to the current value of the timer, by using the value game_Ticks. I have tried using button constructors and using code such as time_Display.Text(game_Ticks) but it says that it cannot be used as a method.

```
time_Display.Text(game_Ticks / 50);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `time_Display` is a UI control with a `.Text` property then that is indeed not a method, it's a property:

```
time_Display.Text = (game_Ticks / 50).ToString();
```